# How to register component in multiple module.ts files

Tags: angular6

Can we register the same component in multiple `module.ts` files?. If so, what are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we register (the) same component in multiple module.ts files?

No. In order to re-use a single component all over your app, you have to create a shared module which declares and exports the component. Then, import this shared module everywhere you need the component.

SharedModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    YourComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    YourComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

FeatureOneModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class FeatureOneModule {
}
```

FeatureTwoModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class FeatureTwoModule {
}
```

You will then be able to use `YourComponent` in `FeatureOne` and `FeatureTwo`-Module accordingly.
Angular offers a great [guide here](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules).

Comment: Nice explanation.